# deluge daemon on server 15.10?

Tags: server, deluge

Can someone help me get deluged running on 15.10?  Every how-to I can find is for init.d not systemd.

The deluged package installs no startup scripts for either init.d (which would work in compatibility mode) or systemd. So what do you need to do to get systemd to start deluged?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy deluged`

Comment: Honestly! What's unclear?  deluged installs no startup scripts for systemd. Or, for that matter, for init. So, he's asking how to start it.

Comment: OK, I edited his question to make it clear what he was asking, you've accepted my edits, and you still haven't reopened the question. I'd post an answer in the comments, but I don't have enough space!

Answer (score -1):

`init.d` - the Init-System is "dead" - but the **script** itself is still existing in `/etc/init.d/deluged`.

`deluged` - installed from the Ubuntu repository - **does not contain a native systemd service**!

It redirects to `systemd-sysv-install`.

You can verify this by executing `sudo systemctl disable deluged.service`.

The output shows that currently no native script exists:

```
deluged.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable deluged
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `deluged' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `deluged' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

Anyway you should use `systemctl`.

---

Install

```
sudo apt-get install deluged
```

Start/Stop/Restart …

```
sudo systemctl start deluged.service 
sudo systemctl stop deluged.service 
sudo systemctl restart deluged.service
```

Comment: Im getting this:    Process: 1340 ExecStart=/usr/bin/deluged -d (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: This is a misleading answer as far as I am aware there are no systemd files included with current deluge packages.

Comment: A basic user will have no idea what you are talking about and you have put steps in there that indicate the user should stop and start the service so not really helping at all. There are perfectly working service scripts on the Deluge site with comprehensive steps on how to use them.

Comment: Oh and since this is obviously a packaging issue with Deluge this whole question should be closed and redirected to a Launchpad bug.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be closed. Of course there should be a launchpad bug, but we still need to know how to start deluged (in my case, I actually _had_ a working systemd start, and something removed it...)

Comment: btw, if there were actually init.d files, it shouldn't need a systemd service file - they get pulled in, anyway, but there isn't one...