# Error when starting deluge daemon on systemd

Tags: server, systemd, deluge

trying to start deluge daemon (deluged) on Ubuntu 15.10 but I'm getting this error on the status:

```
chris@fileserver:~$ systemctl status deluged
● deluged.service - Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/deluged.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2015-10-26 09:52:26 EDT; 51min ago
  Process: 1340 ExecStart=/usr/bin/deluged -d (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1340 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Oct 26 09:52:26 fileserver systemd[1]: deluged.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 26 09:52:26 fileserver systemd[1]: deluged.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 26 09:52:26 fileserver systemd[1]: deluged.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 26 09:52:26 fileserver systemd[1]: Stopped Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon.
Oct 26 09:52:26 fileserver systemd[1]: deluged.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 26 09:52:26 fileserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon.
Oct 26 09:52:26 fileserver systemd[1]: deluged.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 26 09:52:26 fileserver systemd[1]: deluged.service: Failed with result 'start-limit'.
```

Comment: This is a bug report so offtopic for AskUbuntu plus you already have an existing question asking essentially the same thing:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/690157/deluge-daemon-on-server-15-10

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy deluged`